# c++ Parsing prices of a text file

Tags: c++, parsing

I need to parse the following file so it takes the item as a string then skip the # sign and then take the price as a float.
text file:

```
hammer#9.95
saw#20.15
shovel#35.40
```

how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do think twice about using a `float` to represent prices; use a currency-type class instead. This is because `float` can't represent decimal quantities precisely. You also should submit what you've tried so far: SO is not a free solution provider.

Comment: Seconding Bathsheba. Something as simple as `0.1` cannot be represented precisely in a `float`.

Answer (score 2):

Read the file line by line into a string. Find `#` and parse second part as float.

```
std::ifstream file("input.txt");

for (std::string line; std::getline(file, line); )
{
    auto sharp = line.find('#'); // std::size_t sharp = ... 

    if (sharp != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::string name(line, 0, sharp);

        line.erase(0, sharp+1);

        float price = std::stof(line);

        std::cout << name << " " << price << "\n";
    }
}
```

Note: I didn't some error checking, do them yourself as an exercise. and also you should know about [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream), [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::stof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof).

Comment: `auto sharp`: +1 for being flashy.

Comment: Note that this will only work on C++11 compiler.

Comment: @yuyoyuppe: So what? C++11 is two years old, C++14 is one year away. About time people start *using* those features.

Comment: @DevSolar I agree, but unfortunately there are still people out there using VC6.0 and being completely unaware of the new standard.

Comment: @yuyoyuppe: That's a problem of the people still using pre-C++98 crappy compilers. It's definitely not a reason to crimp your coding style. You don't limit your Java coding to AWT either just because some people out there haven't heard of Java 2 yet.

Comment: @DevSolar ...and I do use modern compiler. But you can't force the whole world to start using the newest tools. The only reason I noted C++11 compatibility is people who aren't aware of the new standard(maybe the author of the question).

Answer (score 2):

In case when you have std::string in presented format you could use something like this:

```
std::string test {"test#5.23"};
std::cout << std::stof(std::string{test.begin() + test.rfind('#') + 1, test.end()});
```

Note that std::stof is C++11 function